# No partition on USB Flash Drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, partition-recovery

A friend gave me a corrupted USB memory stick to try recovery data from.  But I've had some unusual results, so thought I'd share to see if anyone is familiar with this problem...

- First off I just tried opening from my own PC.  Windows prompted to Format the drive, which I of course declined
- Downloaded TestDisk to anaylsis the drive.  And right away I noticed something strange, on the listed drives it comes up as

> Disk /dev/sdc - 6144 B - USB Flash Drive

- That's right, the first USB flash drive smaller than a floppy disk!?
- Moving on anyway... first anaylsis comes up with:

> Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55

- TestDisk's Quick Search gave no results, moved on to Deeper Search:

> No partition found or selected for recovery

- This left me stumped.  I tired a couple of other programs with no success
- I did manage to get a backup image, but it was just as small as TestDisk indicated, so nothing of use on it
- After a few hours trying various suggestions from other sources, I gave in and just tried formatting the drive.  But returned the message:

> Windows was unable to complete the format.

- From googling that, the suggestion was to delete the partition.  But there is no partition to delete in this case.
- most recently I've tried formatting from cmd, and got this result:

> Format D: /FS:FAT32
>
> The type of the file system is RAW
>
> The new file system is FAT32
>
> Verifying 0M
>
> 11 bad sectors were encountered during the format. These sectors cannot be guaranteed to have been cleaned
>
> The volume is too small for FAT32

Anyone got any suggestions?

---

UPDATE: As per suggestion from @Karen, I tried running a `CLEAN` from `DISKPART`, results as follows

> DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be preformed because of an I/O device error.

Comment: Try `diskpart`, `select` the correct `disk`, then `clean`, or try something like GParted from Linux. OTOH all those bad sectors probably mean the drive's a goner.

Comment: @Karen GParted didn't even see the USB device.  I tried Diskpart and updated my question with the results.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: `DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be preformed because of an I/O device error.`  That's not a good error to get; something's happening at the hardware level (either in the firmware of the USB drive, or the flash memory itself is corrupted).  Either way, I'd say that drive is toast now... Sorry :(  IMHO, if you can't get anything back with TestDisk, and you can't even format the drive because of I/O errors, time to get a new one...  If you want to do a sector check, you can try doing a `chkdsk -r` on it, or a **full** format.

Comment: @Breakthrough ah okay, thanks for explanation.  At least I don't have to spend anymore time on it :).  I'll go break the bad news to my friend.

Comment: You can try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/728812/usb-not-recognized-or-showing-a-drive-letter/1015514#1015514) , just saying, it could help.